# Sending event to Orion from Cepheus

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am using the latest version of orangeopensource/fiware-cepheus from GitHub.

The problem is that based on some existing examples my Cepheus-broker doesn't send any events to Orion which I explicitly declared on the "/tmp/cep-default-.json" file. It produces the following results on the log:

```
cepheus_1      | 2016-09-27 17:03:20.209  INFO 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.o.cepheus.cep.EsperEventProcessor      : EventIn: Event{type='Position', values={id=Room34, key=24}}
cepheus_1      | 2016-09-27 17:03:20.840  INFO 10 --- [Timer-default-0] c.orange.cepheus.cep.EventSinkListener   : EventOut: position / id:24 from insert into position select key as id from Position.win:time(10 minutes) group by key output last every 10 seconds
```

But the messages of success or error won't show. This could mean 2 things on [EventSinkListener.java](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/blob/355e0d7a4859f851659e472981a03be916865321/cepheus-cep/src/main/java/com/orange/cepheus/cep/EventSinkListener.java):

1. updateContext is null (line 76)
2. eventTypeOut.getBrokers() returns a null broker (line 79)

My cep-default-.json is as follows

```
{
  "host":"http://localhost:8080",
    "in":[
{
  "id":"position",
  "type":"Position",
  "attributes":[
    { "name":"key", "type":"string"}
  ]
}
    ],
    "out":[
      {
        "id":"position",
        "type":"Position",
        "attributes":[
          { "name":"key", "type":"string"}
        ],
        "brokers": [
          {
            "url":"http://172.17.0.3:1026",
            "serviceName": "myHome",
            "servicePath": "/enviroment"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "statements":[
      "INSERT INTO position SELECT key as id FROM Position.win:time(10 min) GROUP BY key OUTPUT LAST EVERY 10 sec"
    ]
  }
```

Being confused about this I tried [Example 4](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/blob/master/doc/examples/4_CepAndBrokerAndOrion/index.md) changing the broker address (localhost:8082) to my Orion address (http://172.17.0.3:1026). But when running the script it prints the following:

```
UpdateContext failed for http://localhost:8082: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I confirmed that http://172.17.0.3:1026 is used as the broker address on the config file, but it still uses localhost:8082 somehow.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you changing the adress ? Are you using the provided scripts ? The /tmp/cep-xxx.json are not intended to be edited by the user, its the current persisted CEP configuration.